# Android - How to display Backstack Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

When `btn` will be clicked Fragment 1 will be displayed, when I press `btn2` Fragment 2 will be displayed and I believe Fragment 1 is placed in the backstack. The second time around, when I clicked the `btn`, I wanted to display its previous state. I'll include code that made me very confused and I am not sure how to do it.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
String str = "frag1";
Fragment videoFragment = new VideoPlayerFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.child_fragment, videoFragment, str);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit(); 
}
});

btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
String str2 ="frag1";
String str3 ="frag2";
//FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry=
//getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getActivity().getFragmentManager().
//getBackStackEntryCount()-1);
//String str3 = backEntry.getName();
//Fragment fragment= getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(str3);

Fragment videoFragment = new CopyOfVideoPlayerFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction2.addToBackStack(str2);
transaction2.replace(R.id.child_fragment, videoFragment, str3);
transaction2.commit(); 
}
});
```

**Confusing Code and not working:**

```
FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry=getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getActivity().getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()-1);
String str3 = backEntry.getName();
Fragment fragment= getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(str3);
```

Comment: So the second time you clicked btn, you want to display Fragment1 again right?

Comment: Yes, so i wanted to check if this is the second time that btn is clicked, if yes then get its saved state and display it again putting fragment 2 in backstack. But also, I have no idea in getting the prev backtack. having errors with my backEntry.

Comment: If you want to keep `Fragment2` in backstack too, you have to add `Fragment1` again so `Fragment2` can be added to backstack.

Comment: sorry I mean, putting Fragment 2 in backstack and displaying the Fragment 1's saved state

Answer (score 0):

For displaying previous fragtment (the one in backStack) , use this code:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransaction();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you guide me or provide additional code to check if what state is fragment 1 have, if there is a need to display backtack. I am not sure how to use the code above sir.

Comment: That you can control in onSaveBundleInstances(Bundle inBundle) of the fragment, and you'll get the same bundle in onCreate(Bundle outBundle) of the same fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I think there the following way can accomplish your requirement,

1.create a fragment manager to hold a reference of this two fragment.

2.each time when you click the button, remove the old, add the new.

the code

```
     FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     ft.remove(fragment1);
     ft.add(fragment2);
```